# Nuxt.js front end and laravel api on same nginx server Digital ocean

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ubuntu, nginx, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt application SPA for the front end and a laravel API.   Nuxt calls on API for request.   I am trying to deploy this in one digital ocean droplet but I am having problems with it.   My laravel application seems to be working but I cant get nuxt to show here is my set up

Ubuntu 20
nginx 1.18
php 7.4

laravel nginx server block

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name DROPLET_IP;
    root /var/www/laravel-api/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
```

}

here is my nuxt server block:

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name DROPLET_IP;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/nuxt-front/dist;

    }
}
```

both of these are in their own sites-available and symlink to sites enable.

for some reason when I access `http://DROPLET_IP:3000`. it just hangs.

Is there a special way I should be doing this to run as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Use root

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    root /var/www/nuxt-front/dist;    
  
}
```

or

use proxy pass

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```